# kNN to predict LPR

Tags: python-3.x, knn

I am doing a License Plate Recognition system using python. I browsed through the net and I found many people have done the recognition of characters in the license plate using kNN algorithm.

Can anyone explain how we predict the characters in the License Plate using kNN ?

Is there any other algorithm or method that can do the prediction better ?

I am referring to this Git repo https://github.com/MicrocontrollersAndMore/OpenCV_3_License_Plate_Recognition_Python

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did this 5 years ago. I will suggest you that, maybe right now is so much better to do this using ML Classifier Models, but if you want to use OpenCV. OpenCV has a pretty cool way to make ANPR using an OCR.

When I did it, I used a RasberryPi for processing and capture images and with c++ run openCV in another computer. I recommend you check this repo and if you're interested look for the book reference there. I hope my answer helps you to find your solution.

https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code.